# Excluding column from gather() from tidyr package using standard evaluation

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to exclude a column from `gather()` from the tidyr package using standard evaluation.

Using non-standard evaluation, this works fine:

```
mtcars_df <- head(mtcars[, c("mpg", "hp", "cyl")])
tidyr::gather(mtcars_df, key, val, -cyl)
```

However, using standard evaluation, neither of the following work and both return an error:

```
tidyr::gather_(mtcars_df, "key", "val", -"cyl")
tidyr::gather_(mtcars_df, "key", "val", -cyl)
```

As a work-around, I tried to use the `select()` helper function `contains()`, but this just returned the original `data.frame`, `mtcars_df`:

```
tidyr::gather_(mtcars_df, "key", "val", -dplyr::contains("cyl"))
```

How can I exclude a column in this way using standard evaluation? What's going on here?

Comment: It's more work, but `mtcars_df %>% gather_('key', 'value', names(.)[names(.) != 'cyl'])`. There may be a simpler idiom, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to tidyr github issue [#109: gather_ no longer supports dropping a column?](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/109),

> gather_() only works with character vectors. - Hadley Wickham, 2015

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars_df %>% tidyr::gather_("key", "val", setdiff(names(.), "cyl"))
```

Comment: For submitting to CRAN, as pointed out by @Dom, this would work: `mtcars_df %>% tidyr::gather_("key", "val", names(mtcars_df)[names(mtcars_df) != "cyl"])`

Answer (score 1):

Altough your workaround works, it creates a `NOTE` when used in a package:

```
no visible binding for global variable '.'
```

Which prevents it from being published on CRAN :(

Is there any other way to exclude column with `gather_` using standart evaluation?

I've tried many things (such as using `dplyr::select_vars`) but nothing worked...

Comment: I think I had this same issue but failed to acknowledge it here: My solution (I forget how I came to this so if it was from someone else - thanks! :)) was: `mtcars_df %>% tidyr::gather_("key", "val", names(mtcars_df)[names(mtcars_df) != "cyl"])` which should work when being published to CRAN