# Plot trends for group of certain types using R

Tags: r, plot

I have this sample of dataset,

```
d <- read.table(text=Type   Year    V1  V2  V4  V7  V10 V13 V23
M   2017    0.021836007 0.032531194 0.069964349 0.032531194 0.021836007 0.021836007 0.021836007
M   2017    0.025067751 0.041327913 0.049457995 0.122628726 0.073848238 0.016937669 0.041327913
M   2016    0.327145215 0.099422442 0.020214521 0.054867987 0.044966997 0.015264026 0.020214521
M   2015    0.025205761 0.025205761 0.019032922 0.04372428  0.019032922 0.031378601 0.012860082
M   2014    0.018992248 0.046899225 0.418992248 0.009689922 0.009689922 0.009689922 0.05620155
M   2013    0.021491228 0.400438596 0.010964912 0.010964912 0.026754386 0.026754386 0.010964912
M   2012    0.016059028 0.010850694 0.031684028 0.026475694 0.042100694 0.052517361 0.016059028
M   2012    0.036333333 0.100333333 0.228333333 0.028333333 0.024333333 0.020333333 0.020333333
M   2011    0.016577061 0.027329749 0.016577061 0.059587814 0.134856631 0.016577061 0.038082437
T   2017    0.035240464 0.080016584 0.03026534  0.045190713 0.055140962 0.03026534  0.025290216
T   2016    0.01712963  0.01712963  0.033796296 0.31712963  0.06712963  0.028240741 0.01712963
T   2016    0.016059028 0.010850694 0.026475694 0.026475694 0.010850694 0.021267361 0.031684028
T   2015    0.034385113 0.058656958 0.087783172 0.014967638 0.034385113 0.014967638 0.014967638
L   2017    0.018244576 0.018244576 0.047830375 0.101084813 0.012327416 0.047830375 0.018244576
L   2017    0.016488414 0.016488414 0.01114082  0.01114082  0.016488414 0.460338681 0.016488414
L   2016    0.022671569 0.03002451  0.022671569 0.015318627 0.015318627 0.03002451  0.022671569
L   2016    0.072791165 0.133032129 0.012550201 0.03062249  0.054718876 0.012550201 0.036646586
L   2015    0.020419426 0.020419426 0.020419426 0.040286976 0.020419426 0.027041943 0.027041943
L   2015    0.013796909 0.020419426 0.013796909 0.020419426 0.040286976 0.027041943 0.046909492
L   2015    0.042840376 0.014671362 0.014671362 0.028755869 0.028755869 0.021713615 0.014671362
L   2014    0.071969697 0.026515152 0.020021645 0.039502165 0.08495671  0.033008658 0.026515152
L   2013    0.050184162 0.017034991 0.011510129 0.039134438 0.017034991 0.011510129 0.028084715
', header=TRUE)
```

I have tried to gather the data before plotting the graphs,but  got error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Type' not found`

```
library(tidyr)
d2 <- gather(d, Variable, Value, -Type, -Year)
```

At the end, I would like to see the trends between types (M, T and L), and the values from `V1  V2  V4  V7  V10 V13 V23`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Unfortunately `gather` does not let you drop columns

```
# tidy data
newd <- d %>%
          gather(key, value, V1, V2, V4, V7, V10, V13, V23)

# plot        
ggplot(data=newd, aes(x=Year, y=value, color=interaction(Type, key))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()
```

If you insist on dropping columns, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285006/excluding-column-from-gather-from-tidyr-package-using-standard-evaluation)

Comment: still get an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V1' not found`

Comment: It works, after I replace unnecessary spaces in my original data.